# How to debug delete() in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

how to debug `delete()` in CakePHP? When I do:

```
debug($this->Sessions->delete($s));
```

I get this error:

```
{
    "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column \u0027session_id\u0027 in \u0027where clause\u0027",
    "url": "\/api\/sessions\/delete\/2856",
    "code": 500,
    "file": "\/var\/www\/vendor\/cakephp\/cakephp\/src\/Database\/Statement\/MysqlStatement.php",
    "line": 39
}
```

EDIT: Figured out my problem, I had called the session_id column "sessions_id" in the table by mistake. I updated this, and it solved my problem. However I'd really like to know how to debug `delete()` and `find()` properly. I noticed there is a debugging console `bin/cake console`. Then `help` to debug stuff, but I dont know how to use it, and cant seem to find any documentation on this. Can anyone help out? Thanks.

Comment: You should probably clarify what exactly you mean when you say "_debug_".

Comment: @ndm Provide a more detailed error message, and ideally, along with a backtrace to the exact line causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error message stems directly from the DBMS, not from CakePHP, and it tells you pretty much all you need to know about why the query failed, there's not really a way to get more info on that.

Unless you're talking about the line where the exception is being thrown, pointing to a specific line would be rather complicated, as in this case there isn't an exact line causing a problem, the CakePHP side is working perfectly fine, you just mis-configured/named things, which led to a non-working SQL query being generated.

I would suggest to use a proper IDE and a debugger like XDebug that can halt on exceptions, then you have your stacktrace and a bunch of contextual information right at hand, and you can easily step through the code. A plain stacktrace can also be found in the logs (`/logs/*.log`).